# Searching for a string a column in datatable

Tags: c#

I am getting a datatable object of a certain type from strongly typed dataset, now I want to find out if one of the column "Title" has certain string in it.

I am trying this, is there any better way ?

```
   FruitDataAccess fda = new FruitDataAccess();
   FruitDataTable fdt = cda.GetFriuts(fruitCrateID);
   DataTable dt = fdt.CopyToDataTable();
   var row = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(r => r.ItemArray.Any(c => c.ToString().Contains("whatever")));
```

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Linq`?

Comment: I added reference to System.Linq, but when I click on Cast to add a reference automatically, it doesn't says add a reference, let me try

Comment: @CustomizedName, it is an extension method. You will not get the option to resolve in visual studio. You have to explicitly specify `using System.Linq;` in your code

Comment: @Habib you are right, thank you, Simon thank you as well, I edited it

Comment: Are you just trying to get data rows out of a data table as if you are you don't need to cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LINQ TO DataSet/DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx)  like:

```
var search = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .FirstOrDefault(r=> r.Field<string>("Title") == "your string");

if(search != null)
{
    //found
}
```

You can also find rows with your condition like:

```
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = dt.Select("Title Like '%your string%'"); //similar to Contains
```

See: [How to: Locate a Specific Row in a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx)

Comment: very nice, do you have skype ?